# Excel, how to make a graph with different steps than those you've used in your table?

Tags: excel

Ok, I'm having troubles here.

I'd like to make a graph from this table:

[image: My info I'd like to graph]

The problem is that I don't want the graph to use the scale I used in my table, since my scale is completely unusable. My graph looks like this:

[image: The (wrong) graph I'm getting now]

I want to make Excel ignore my scale, and use steps like 1 mL for the horizontal axis. I'm using Excel 2010.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This what I get when I select the dataset and insert an XY Scatter:

[image]

(which seems a bit more like a pH curve IMO!)

Now, you can change the axis setting by right clicking on it:

[image]

[image]

[image]

You might also want to use some gridlines to help reading the graph, which you can insert via:

[image]

Comment: Oops, it should have been NaOH, oh well. Pictures are set now.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I think the issue we had was that we've used a function to determine the values for the x-axis, which makes Excel think it was a text string.

Comment: @AlexandervanCitters Ahh, that should be it. I saw you using `,` in your picture but some languages like French use them for the decimal, so didn't think much about it ^^;

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an XY / Scatter chart type

Comment: I think I'm already doing that, but I'm unsure. How do I create _XY / Scatter chart type_?